# Reading smart contract function - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I'm trying to read total supply from this smart contract, I have checked the ABI and the read does not require arguments. Why am I getting this error?

Imported the ABI from Etherscan with a valid API key
Connected Infura node with valid api.

Please help. I'm new!

Error:

```
Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="TOTAL_SUPPLY()", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)

reason: null,
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  method: 'TOTAL_SUPPLY()',
  data: '0x',
  errorArgs: null,
  errorName: null,
  errorSignature: null,
  address: '0xFc7a5BD22dFc48565D6f04698E566Dd0C71d3155',
  args: [],
  transaction: {
    data: '0x902d55a5',
    to: '0xFc7a5BD22dFc48565D6f04698E566Dd0C71d3155',
    from: '0xa9519a76981489Cf44a6b1023C53EA674B9365fB'
  }
}
```

CODE:

```
const ethers = require("ethers");

async function main() {

    // make an API call to the ABIs endpoint 
    const response = await fetch('https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=0x31Cd7378715174e2c5Bd7EDF9984c9bC2A9209Eb&apikey=xxx');
    const data = await response.json();

    let abi = data.result;
    /*console.log(abi);*/

    // creating a new Provider, and passing in our node URL
    const node = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/xxx";
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(node);

    // initiating a new Wallet, passing in our private key to sign transactions
    let privatekey = "xxx";
    let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privatekey, provider);

    // print the wallet address
    console.log("Using wallet address " + wallet.address);

    // specifying the deployed contract address
    let contractaddress = "0xFc7a5BD22dFc48565D6f04698E566Dd0C71d3155";

    // initiating a new Contract
    let contract = new ethers.Contract(contractaddress, abi, wallet);
    console.log("Using contract address " + contract.address);

    // calling the "retrieve" function to read the stored value
    let supply = await contract.TOTAL_SUPPLY();
    console.log("Value stored in contract is " + supply.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're retrieving ABI of address [0x31Cd7378715174e2c5Bd7EDF9984c9bC2A9209Eb](https://etherscan.io/address/0x31Cd7378715174e2c5Bd7EDF9984c9bC2A9209Eb) on the Ethereum mainnet.
2. Your `ethers` provider correctly connects to the Ethereum mainnet.
3. But then it's trying to interact (call function `TOTAL_SUPPLY()`) with contract on address [0xFc7a5BD22dFc48565D6f04698E566Dd0C71d3155](https://etherscan.io/address/0xFc7a5BD22dFc48565D6f04698E566Dd0C71d3155).

Since there's no contract on the `0xFc...` address on the Ethereum mainnet, the call fails.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried [web3client.app](https://workspace.web3client.app/evm?web3ClientToken=50f4540e-e813-48a0-8cac-e2bd762a86ea).

You can test any abi methods across 500+ chains in any smart contracts.

Identify which network your contract resides and do test it out.

It has code generate feature that lets you to easily get a bug free high quality code